# cocos2dx error Build dynamic library for project failed

Tags: android

'cocos' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
E:\cocos2d-x-3.14.1\build>python android-build.py -p 21 cpp-tests

Answer (score 0):

Is your cocos is configure correctly? Try this, Open your cmd(command prompt) and type `cocos`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSfDM.png)

Answer (score 0):

cmd not recognize cocos because **cocos2d-x-3.14.1\tools\cocos2d-console\bin** folder is not exist into environment path variable.

run `python setup.py` from your cocos2d-x-3.14.1 folder, before building test project.

`setup.py` set required Environment Variables, if already set then good otherwise prompt to set required `NDK_ROOT`, `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, `ANT_ROOT`, `COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT`, `COCOS_X_ROOT`, `COCOS_TEMPLETS_ROOT`

> **COCOS_CONSOLE_ROO**T is path to cocos2d-x-3.14.1\tools\cocos2d-console\bin

bin folder containing **cocos.bat** file that run **cocos.py** script

Answer (score 0):

try this

switch from ndk9b to ndk9d. 
the recent version of cocos2dx made a switch from ndk9b to ndk9d.

i hope thats helpfull for you